# OpenCV+Processing - FaceDetection on a Movie

Tags: opencv, video, processing, detection, face-detection

I am using Processing with the OpenCV Lib and wanted to rewrite the example Code from the creators Git so that instead of doing Face Detection on a Camera Capture I'll load a video (.mp4).

Link to the Git and the example Code (which is working):
[Link](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/LiveCamTest/LiveCamTest.pde)

Here is my Sketch:

```
import processing.video.*;
import gab.opencv.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

OpenCV opencv;
Movie myMovie;
Rectangle[] faces;

void setup() {
  size(480, 270);

  myMovie = new Movie(this, "people3.mp4");
  myMovie.loop();
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, myMovie.width, myMovie.height);
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);
}

void movieEvent(Movie myMovie) {
  myMovie.read();
}

void draw() {

  background(0);
  if (myMovie.available()) {    

    opencv.loadImage(myMovie);
    faces = opencv.detect();
    image(myMovie, 0, 0);

    if (faces != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        noFill();
        rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm getting is an

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0

at openCV.loadImage(myMovie) and I don't know why.

Appreciating any help!

Comment: If I were you, I'd try [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and taking those steps on one at a time. For example, can you just get a basic sketch that shows a movie playing?

Comment: Did you read this one? https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18536/opencv-problem-with-bootcamp

Comment: @Harry been there done that :) But it's still not working. When you check the official openCV Reference you can also find code that implies that it should be possible to use a Movie argument on a loadImage() function.

Answer (score 1):

Made it work. Don't ask me why, but it's necessary to call both the Movie.loop() and Movie.play() function.. Here you go:

```
import processing.video.*;
import gab.opencv.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

OpenCV opencv;
Movie myMovie;
Rectangle[] faces;

void setup() {
  size(480, 270);

  myMovie = new Movie(this, "people3.mp4");
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 480, 270);

  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);
  myMovie.loop();
  myMovie.play();
}

void draw() {
   //Movie needs time to load into canvas, so we wait until we get a height
   while (myMovie.height == 0 )  delay(10); 
   image(myMovie, 0, 0);
   opencv.loadImage(myMovie);
   faces = opencv.detect();


  if (faces != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      strokeWeight(2);
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      noFill();
      rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
    }
  }
}


void movieEvent(Movie myMovie) {
  myMovie.read();
}
```